# In Android OS, Can I create a service that runs in the background and detects if the Loud Speaker is ON or OFF?

Tags: android, service, speaker

I need to create a service which runs in the background and detects if the phone loud-speaker is being used. I need to listen for a phone "loud-speaker event" (ON or OFF) and perform an action depends on the state of the loud speaker.

Comment: you means Headphones plugged or not ?? (headphones pluged means speak is off vice versa headphones unplugged means speaker is on .)

Comment: I need my service to know every time the Speaker (not ringer) is used. Lets say a conversation is going on and the user put the Phone Speaker ON, I need my service to react to it.

Comment: you can.. i need to know what do you mean by Speaker ?? mediavolume or headphones plugging or some other things ? i think you are mentioning about loudspeak on and off while user in call right ?

Comment: Yes, I mean the loudspeaker while in call.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a `BroadcastReceiver` with the `AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED` action, which will be fired when the sound profile changes. Inside the `onReceiver()` you can call `AudioManager`'s `getRingerMode()` method, which will return `RINGER_MODE_NORMAL`, `RINGER_MODE_SILENT` or `RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE`. Hope this helps.

Comment: would the AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED be fired no matter which application is using the speaker?

Comment: dear Egor, I think I was misunderstood.. I need my service to know every time the Speaker (not ringer) is used. Lets say a conversation is going on and the user puts the Phone Speaker ON, I need my service to react to it.(and to OFF state as well)

Comment: @Rami, Then you would probably want to edit your question to make it more clear for the others.

Comment: I certainly agree with you, nevertheless do you have an answer to my question please?